# Sublime sublimelinter error - No such file or directory -- rubocop (LoadError)

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter, rubocop

i using oh-my-zsh, and i have installed gem - rubocop, also i added to sublime setting

```
"paths":
{
    "osx":
    [
        "/Users/valerijtutaev/.rbenv/shims"
    ]
},
```

but linter looking to wrong directory - /usr/bin/ruby

how can i tell to looking in to "/Users/valerijtutaev/.rbenv/shims" instead of "/usr/bin/ruby" ?

Comment: Do you have a `.ruby-version` file in your project root?

Comment: @Drenmi yes, i have
.ruby-version: 2.4.1     ,
ruby -v: 
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]

Comment: Try setting `rbenv global 2.4.1`. Does it help?